# Locally constant dimensions

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm concerned about the following problem from Lang's *Algebra*.

> **15.** Let $A$ be a Noetherian local ring. Let $E$ be a finite $A$-module. Assume that $A$ has no nilpotent elements. For each prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$, let $k(\mathfrak{p})$ be the residue class field. If $\dim_{k(\mathfrak{p})} E_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}E_\mathfrak{p}$ is constant for all $\mathfrak{p}$, show that $E$ is free. [*Hint*: Let $x_1, \dotsc, x_r \in E$ be such that the residue classes mod the maximal ideal form a basis for $E/\mathfrak{m}E$ over $k(\mathfrak{m})$. We get a surjective homomorphism
>   $$
>  A^r \to E \to 0.
> $$
>   Let $J$ be the kernel. Show that $J_\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathfrak{p}_\mathfrak{p} A^r_\mathfrak{p}$ for all $\mathfrak{p}$ so $J \subset \mathfrak{p}A^r$ for all $\mathfrak{p}$ and $J = 0$.]

For each prime $\mathfrak{p}$,
$\dim_{k(\mathfrak{p})} E_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}E_{\mathfrak{p}}
= \dim_{k(\mathfrak{m})} E_{\mathfrak{m}}/\mathfrak{m}E_{\mathfrak{m}}
= \dim_{k(\mathfrak{m})} E/\mathfrak{m}E
= r$.

There is an exact sequence
$$
0
\to J_{\mathfrak{p}}
\to A^r_{\mathfrak{p}}
\to E_{\mathfrak{p}}
\to 0
$$

and there is a morphism of short exact sequences from that down to
$$
0
\to \ker
\to A^r_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}A^r_{\mathfrak{p}}
\to E_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}E_{\mathfrak{p}}
\to 0.
$$

The $k(\mathfrak{p})$-dimension of the middle term is $\leq r$, and that of the next term is $r$, so the surjection is an isomorphism and $\ker = 0$. Hence for all $\mathfrak{p}$, $J_{\mathfrak{p}} \subset \mathfrak{p} A^r_{\mathfrak{p}}$, implying $J \subset \mathfrak{p}A^r$ $(*)$. Since $A$ has no nilpotent elements, $\bigcap_{\mathfrak{p}}\mathfrak{p}A^r = 0$, implying $J = 0$.

I'm worried because I didn't use the Noetherian hypothesis. Is something wrong?

---

Justification of $(*)$:

Let $\{y_i\}$ be a basis for $A^r$. Suppose $a = \sum a_iy_i \in J$. We know that $a/1 \in \mathfrak{p}A^r_{\mathfrak{p}}$, i.e., $a/1 = (1/s)\sum b_iy_i$ for some $s \notin \mathfrak{p}$, and $b_i \in \mathfrak{p}$. So for some $t \notin \mathfrak{p}$, $tsa = t\sum b_iy_i$. On the other hand, $tsa = \sum tsa_iy_i$, hence each $tsa_i \in \mathfrak{p}$. By primeness, each $a_i \in \mathfrak{p}$, so $a \in \mathfrak{p}A^r$.

Comment: The conclusion is that $A$ is not necessarily noetherian. (+1 for the question and for the proof of $(*)$.)

Comment: I'm also using Lang's Algebra but in the version I'm using the hint says to show that $J_p\subset m_pA_p^r$ so $J\subset p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative proof which doesn't use that $A$ is noetherian.

By Nakayama Lemma we get that $x_1,\dots,x_r$ is a (minimal) system of generators for $E$.

> Claim: The elements $x_1,\dots,x_r$ form an $A$-basis for $E$.

Suppose we have $\sum_{i=1}^ra_ix_i=0$. Then this holds in $E_{\mathfrak p}$, and also in $E_{\mathfrak p}/\mathfrak pE_{\mathfrak p}$. But (the images of) $x_1,\dots,x_r$ form a $k(\mathfrak p)$-basis in $E_{\mathfrak p}/\mathfrak pE_{\mathfrak p}$ (why?). It follows $a_i=0$ in $k(\mathfrak p)$ for all $i$, that is, $\frac{a_i}{1}\in\mathfrak pA_{\mathfrak p}$ for all $i$. This entails $a_i\in\mathfrak p$ for all $i$. Since $A$ is reduced we get $a_i=0$ for all $i$, and we are done.